# Will Silverlight 5 be the last in Silverlight web technology?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

This is not a coding question. Just want to know anybody has idea about future of Silverlight as web technology.I know WP 7 is going to use Silverlight but are there any value in converting our existing SL 4 apps to SL 5?

I could see that HTML5 is getting more popular and eliminating the need for browser plug-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: nobody (outside of Microsoft) knows (or is telling if they do know) if there will be another full release of Silverlight. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use it if it has features that benefit you (and it has *many* new features - I've spoken at a TechEd about them).

Also, HTML5 **is not** Silverlight, please do not get them or their functionality confused - they are two different things. For web **applications** I would still use Silverlight. Without getting into a discussion about the merits of each (because that is not what SO is for), Silverlight is aimed at data and workflow driven web applications - you can still do that in HTML5 (especially with some of the libraries available), but you are going to have to do five times* as much coding to achieve the same result.

**Edit:** just in case you didn't notice, Silverlight 5 RTW was released this weekend and is available now. You should go get yourself some of that yummy goodness while it is fresh.

*Maybe a slight exaggeration, but you get my point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont think we should consider HTML 5 is not Silverlight as the RIA comes where there is no support for rich content in html and not html 5 has it. More details are written in my blog.Anyway this question is closed .Hope will get a chance to discuss somewhere. http://silverlightedweb.blogspot.com/2011/12/silverlight-5-released-more-access-or.html